# Change BorderThickness in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, border

I'm really new to WPF and XAML and I'm trying to create a custom button style.

I already have a button template:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="Test" CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Blue">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And a litte animation hovering the button:

```
<Style x:Key="Animation" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource RoundButtonTemplate}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"
                            Duration="0:0:0.400"
                            From="1, 1, 1, 1"
                            To="3, 3, 3, 3"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                            Duration="0:0:0.300"
                            From="22"
                            To="25"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                            Duration="0:0:0.300"
                            From="75"
                            To="78"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style>
```

Everything works fine except the ThicknessAnimation. How could it work?

Comment: have you tried adding `FillBehavior="HoldEnd"` to the ThicknessAnimation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ControlTemplate` replace `BorderThickness="1"` with `BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"`. Your `Style` animates control `BorderThickness` which is not used inside `ControlTemplate` as `Border` uses fixed value.

```
<Style x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border 
               x:Name="Test" 
               CornerRadius="5" 
               Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
               BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
               BorderBrush="Blue">
               <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

You'll also need to add `Setter` with default value like with `Background`. You may also consider doing same thing with `BorderBrush`. It will allow you later to influence `BorderBrush` of your control without changing `Template`